# Salesforce Lookup field showing ID value instead of record name

Tags: salesforce, apex

Hi I have a custom object which has a custom field of type lookup to Account. The child custom record gets created when Account record is created. I am creating child record in after insert trigger on Account and keeping the name of child record same as of the name of Account.

But In the name I am getting 15 digit Id instead of real name of account. What can be the issue?

Code## for Trigger

```
 if(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert)){
     AccountTriggerHelper.createReferrer(Trigger.new);
        }
```

In Apex Class:

```
public static void createReferrer(List<Account> accountList){
        List<Referral__c> newReferral = new List<Referral__c>();
        for(Account acc : accountList) {
            if(acc.Talos_RecordType__c=='Referrer'){
                system.debug('==acc=1='+acc);
                Referral__c ref = new Referral__c();
                System.debug('-----acc.Name----'+acc.Name);
                ref.Name = acc.Name;
                ref.Account__c = acc.Id;  
                ref.Email__c = acc.PersonEmail;
                ref.Talos_IQOS_Expert_ID__c = acc.Talos_IQOS_Expert_ID__c;
                ref.Talos_Referrer_Type__c = acc.Referrer_Type__c;
                ref.User_Id__c = acc.UserID__c;
                ref.Email_Validation__c = true;
                ref.Store_Code__c = acc.Store_Code__c;
                newReferral.add(ref); 
                system.debug('==referral=1='+newReferral);
            }
        }
```

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: Where are you seeing the name displayed? Are you sure it's the name field? What shows if you run this in the developer console? `SELECT Name FROM Referral__c`

Comment: The name displayed is 15 digit Account Id. I am looking for it in the list, record detailed view.

Comment: Did you run the query?

Comment: Yes, Its 15 digit Id only :(

Answer (score 0):

This code can't lead to population of Id in the Name field. There might be another trigger on Account or child Object, or any workflow, process builder on your org creating that change again. Can you check the created date and modified date of the child record.
If they are different, then most probably I am right.